# Element does not take the focus on Firefox when changing its content on mouse down

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, focus

Say you have a `DIV` with a `TABINDEX` so that it can receive the focus.
Now imagine that on `mousedown` you change the text contained in that `DIV`. On Chrome and Edge, the `DIV` will take the focus. But not on Firefox.

On Firefox, it appears that the clicked text node inside the `DIV` matters. Destroying/replacing it using `innerHTML` or `textContent` will not allow the `DIV` to receive the focus.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gq52bj7o

HTML:

```
<div id="test" tabIndex="0">click here (on the text, not outside)</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
testDiv.addEventListener(
  "mousedown", 
  function ()
  {
   //testDiv.innerHTML = "why Firefox, why?"; // KO
   testDiv.textContent = "why Firefox, why?"; // KO
   //testDiv.firstChild.nodeValue = "why Firefox, why?"; // OK
  });
```

Notice that if you preserve the existing text node (`testDiv.firstChild.nodeValue = "why Firefox, why?";`) all works as expected. Also, if you click outside of the text, the `DIV` also receives the focus.

Is this normal? How would you bypass this behaviour (imagine a bigger application that updates the `textContent` or `innerHTML` of the clicked element -- focus issues would be encountered on Firefox...)?

Comment: *"Say you have a DIV with a TABINDEX so that it can receive the focus. "* Just because you have `tabindex` does not mean that the element can receive the focus. That functionality varies from browser to browser.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes. But as you can see in the Fiddle, the DIV can receive the focus on Firefox, Edge and Chrome on normal circumstences.

Answer (score 0):

just change "mousedown" event to "focus". works in Firefox.

```
testDiv.addEventListener(
    "focus", 
    function ()
  {
   testDiv.textContent = "why Firefox, why?";
  });
```